# Some content does not come with CURL request

Tags: php, javascript, curl, remote-server

i am trying to develop a spider to get data from other sites, just for academic meanings.
Very well, i am trying to crawl this website: http://urlmin.com/ngz
What happens if that:
I can get all the data i want, but the photo's directories.
Why? Because it is loaded with javascript; until here its fine.
Here is the js code that loads the image elements after dom is loaded:

```
    var exibirImg = new ExibirImagens();
exibirImg.Imagens = [

    new ItemImagem(
        '../fotosanuncios/13886-Papucha 20074.JPG',
        '../fotosanuncios/13886-p-Papucha 20074.JPG'),

    new ItemImagem(
        '../fotosanuncios/13886-Motores Novos.JPG',
        '../fotosanuncios/13886-p-Motores Novos.JPG'),

    new ItemImagem(
        '../fotosanuncios/13886-Panther reformada5.JPG',
        '../fotosanuncios/13886-p-Panther reformada5.JPG'),

    new ItemImagem(
        '../fotosanuncios/13886-Panther reformada 2007.JPG',
        '../fotosanuncios/13886-p-Panther reformada 2007.JPG'),

];
exibirImg.PreLoad();
exibirImg.Titulo = 'Oferta A Gtr 323';
exibirImg.EscreveImagens();
exibirImg.TimeOutJs = 3500;
exibirImg.ImagemNotFound = 'imagens/ImagemNotFound.png';
exibirImg.IdImagemPrincipal = 'imagemPrincipalPF';
exibirImg.IdImagemMini = 'imagensPequenasPF';
```

It would be really easy, if my CURL gets the JS like above, but it doesnt.
It comes like this:

```
var exibirImg = new ExibirImagens();
exibirImg.Imagens = [

];
exibirImg.PreLoad();
exibirImg.Titulo = 'Oferta A Gtr 323';
exibirImg.EscreveImagens();
exibirImg.TimeOutJs = 3500;
exibirImg.ImagemNotFound = 'imagens/ImagemNotFound.png';
exibirImg.IdImagemPrincipal = 'imagemPrincipalPF';
exibirImg.IdImagemMini = 'imagensPequenasPF';

exibirImg.Iniciar();
```

Again, the array must be loaded with AJAX or something.
But the real puzzle here is that, if i turn off my browser's javascript support, the array still come with the image's directories. So the only explanation is that it came from Server Side. And question is, if it came from server side, why the hell my curl does not get it?

Thanks, hope someone can understand me.

**You can check that script on the same page in the line 262**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me:

```
$url = 'http://urlmin.com/ngz';

$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

if ( $result =  curl_exec($ch) )
{
    echo $result;
}
else
echo "cURL error: ".curl_error($ch);   

curl_close( $ch );
```

And `$result` contains:

```
var exibirImg = new ExibirImagens();
exibirImg.Imagens = [

    new ItemImagem(
        '../fotosanuncios/13886-Papucha 20074.JPG',
        '../fotosanuncios/13886-p-Papucha 20074.JPG'),

    new ItemImagem(
        '../fotosanuncios/13886-Motores Novos.JPG',
        '../fotosanuncios/13886-p-Motores Novos.JPG'),

    new ItemImagem(
        '../fotosanuncios/13886-Panther reformada5.JPG',
        '../fotosanuncios/13886-p-Panther reformada5.JPG'),

    new ItemImagem(
        '../fotosanuncios/13886-Panther reformada 2007.JPG',
        '../fotosanuncios/13886-p-Panther reformada 2007.JPG'),

];
exibirImg.PreLoad();
```

Comment: BUllocks, anyidea why doesnt for me?

Comment: try save the $result to a file and inspect it. probably you outputs to a browser wrong. or someshing like echo htmlspecialchars($result)

Comment: i have tried that, incredibly i have no ideia why that happens. When i try with the minified it works, but with the real URL it doenst. I have tried in my local server and in my remote server. The same.

Comment: i thought it would have something relationed with the type of the request, http, xlm, could be?

Comment: @FernandoFerrari Avoid lexic like that.

Comment: sorry, i was mad at myself, haha, anyway, thanks for your help!